# Alignment of titles on custom template

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, thesis

I want to use the ETH Zurich [thesis template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/eth-zurich-disco-thesis-template/hkkbptgjgyyr), but I don't like the left alignment of the titles:
[image: Alignment of the titles]

I've been trying to change the .cls file without success. Does anyone know how to do it? maybe forcing it on the .tex file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not associated with them I just liked the style, I will round the question better and try a little bit harder by myself then. Thank you

Comment: Yeah I understood, I will try to put actual code if I can't fix it, I think I recognized the title definitions already.

Comment: Left alignment, I found a bunch flushright's. I think that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `discothesis.cls` and adjust the definition of `\@makechapterhead` by commenting out `\begin{flushright}...\end{flushright}` as follows:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \ifnum\c@part=\@ne              %kai
        \ifnum\c@chapter=\@ne       %kai
        \pagenumbering{arabic}  %kai
        \fi                                         %kai
    \fi                                             %kai

    %\begin{flushright}
        \parindent \z@ \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                \Large \textsc{\@chapapp} \space \thechapter
                \par \nobreak
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        {\Huge \bfseries #1 \par\nobreak}
        \vskip 30\p@
        \hrule
        \vskip 80\p@
    %\end{flushright}
    \par}
```